# Use JpaRepository interaction style without entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I like the idea of using interface, which extends `JpaRepository<T, ID>`. It's very clear and elegant. I also know that this interface is always needs an entity type. But sometimes I don’t have an entity, but I want to use this way of interaction with the DB. I already can use methods which interact with entity `A`(or which doesn't even have an entity) in the `B` entity repository (`JpaRepository<B, ID>`), so obviously this is not a problem for `JPA`. But It's not so clear and elegant. I want something like this:

```
public interface ICustomTableRepo extends JpaRepository<Void, Void> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM custom_table")
    List<Object[]> getAllFromCustomTable();
}
```

I want to annotate method declaration with `@Query` which has SQL query.

You can see that I don't want to use entity in this interface at all. But, of course, `JpaRepository` with `<Void, Void>` does not work.

So, how can I use this or same type of interaction with DB without `EntityManager` and without `JpaRepository` with different entity?

Comment: @VinayHegde sorry, what do you mean "Are you want to use JPA only?"?

Comment: @VinayHegde oh, then yes, ok :)